# FLAG_INSISTENT stop repeating notification sound when another notification popup

Tags: android, audio, push-notification, notifications

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT ;
```

above code work like a charm to notification keeps on repeating notification sound.

**Issue**

When the application sends `FLAG_INSISTENT`  it repeating continuously that's good but suddenly SMS / Whatsapp notification came to the device, and older `FLAG_INSISTENT` sound stop.

I don't know why that's happening. 
Please suggest any solution.